# Display filled form fields in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

as the question specifies I want the filled form entries to display somewhere below the form. 
I have tried to build a string based on each input value. But on hitting submit button nothing shows up and it just scrolls to the top of the page.

```js
$(function() {

  var $name = $("#name");
  var $email = $("#email");
  var $password = $("#password");
  var $mobile = $("#mobile");
  var $textarea = $("#textarea");
  var $filledHtml = "";

  $("form span").hide();

  function isEmailValid() {
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    return emailReg.test($email.val());
  }

  function isPasswordValid() {
    return $password.val().length > 8;
  }

  function isMobileValid() {
    return $mobile.val().length === 10;
  }


  function canSubmit() {
    return isPasswordValid() && isEmailValid() && isMobileValid();
  }

  function passwordEvent() {

    if (isPasswordValid()) {

      $password.next().hide();
      $filledHtml += $password.val() + "<br />";
    } else {

      $password.next().show();
    }
  }

  function emailEvent() {

    if (isEmailValid()) {

      $email.next().hide();
      $filledHtml += $email.val() + "<br />";
    } else {

      $email.next().show();
    }
  }

  function mobileEvent() {

    if (isMobileValid()) {

      $mobile.next().hide();
      $filledHtml += $mobile.val() + "<br /> ";
    } else {

      $mobile.next().show();
    }
  }

  function enableSubmitEvent() {

    $("#submit").prop("disabled", !canSubmit());

  }



  $email.focus(emailEvent).keyup(emailEvent).keyup(enableSubmitEvent);

  $password.focus(passwordEvent).keyup(passwordEvent).keyup(enableSubmitEvent);

  $mobile.focus(mobileEvent).keyup(mobileEvent).keyup(enableSubmitEvent);

  enableSubmitEvent();

  $("#submit").click(function() {
    $filledHtml += $textarea.val();
    $('#filled-data').html(filledHtml).addClass('small');
  });



});
```

```css
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}
body {
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: 'Maven Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* ------------------------------------------------------------Reset Ends----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

#orders-mobile {
  display: none;
}
.group:after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
.btn-login {
  background: #fc9816;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.btn-demo {
  background: #fc9816;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 270px;
  text-align: center;
}
.caption {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.caption h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
header,
footer {
  background: #E9F1F4;
}
footer {
  padding: 10px;
}
footer a {
  color: #5e5e5e;
}
footer .blue {
  color: rgb(62, 138, 213);
}
footer .orange {
  color: orange;
}
footer h3 {
  margin: 0.5em 0;
}
section {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}
.media p,
.media-heading {
  text-align: left;
}
.sec-title {
  margin: 1.2em 0;
  color: rgb(62, 138, 213);
}
.subtitle {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.media-heading {
  color: rgb(62, 138, 213);
}
section#orders,
section#orders-mobile {
  background: #E9F1F4;
  min-height: 700px;
}
.mobile {
  background: url('images/mobile.png') no-repeat;
  width: 370px;
  margin: 0 auto 30px;
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.mobile > img {
  height: 418px;
  width: 239px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 59px;
  left: 39px;
}
.marketplace-tabs span.glyphicon {
  font-size: 4em;
}
.marketplace-tabs .nav-tabs a {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #5e5e5e;
}
.nav-tabs>li.active>a,
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus,
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover {
  color: rgb(62, 138, 213);
  background: transparent;
  border: 0px;
}
.nav-tabs>li>a:hover {
  border-color: transparent;
  background: transparent;
  color: rgb(62, 138, 213);
}
.nav-tabs>li {
  padding: 0 35px;
}
#orders-below {
  background: rgb(62, 138, 213);
  color: #fff;
}
#orders-below .sec-title,
#orders-below a {
  color: #fff;
}
#orders-below .glyphicon {
  font-size: 3em;
}
.form-control {
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 8px 12px !important;
}
.form-control:not(textarea) {
  height: 39px !important;
}
form #submit {
  margin-top: 50px !important;
  font-size: 1.2em !important;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: rgb(62, 138, 213);
  color: #fff;
}
form #submit:hover {
  border: 1px solid rgb(62, 138, 213);
  color: rgb(62, 138, 213);
  background: transparent;
  font-weight: bold;
}
form span {
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgb(62, 138, 213);
  left: 103%;
  top: 5px;
  width: auto;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 9999;
}
form span:after {
  right: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
  border-right-color: #2F558E;
  border-width: 8px;
  margin-top: -8px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 4em;
    margin: 2em 0;
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 3.5em;
    margin: 1.7em 0;
  }
  h3 {
    font-size: 3em;
    margin: 1.5em 0;
  }
  h4 {
    font-size: 2.4em;
    margin: 1.2em 0;
  }
  h5 {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 1em 0;
  }
  h6 {
    font-size: 1.4em;
    margin: 0.7em 0;
  }
  p {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 1.4em 0;
  }
  header {
    background: url('images/header.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 700px;
    position: relative;
  }
  .navbar {
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #BEBEBE;
    border-radius: 0px;
  }
  .navbar-default {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  .navbar-default {
    padding: 10px 0;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2em;
  }
  .navbar-nav li > a {
    color: #fff !important;
    background: transparent;
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
  .navbar-nav li > a:hover {
    color: #5e5e5e !important;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  .btn-login {
    background: #fc9816;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus,
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover {
    background: transparent;
  }
  .caption h1 {
    font-size: 4em;
  }
  .caption {
    color: #fff;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 71px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
  .centered {
    margin-top: 14%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .caption p,
  .caption .btn-demo {
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
  section#orders {
    position: relative;
  }
  section#orders .position-mobile {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    right: -450px;
    width: 346px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1280px) {
  .marketplace-tabs span.glyphicon {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
  section {
    padding: 10px !important;
  }
  .nav-tabs > li {
    padding: 0px;
  }
  .marketplace-tabs .nav-tabs a {
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
  section#orders .col-sm-7 {
    padding: 0px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1425px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
    margin: 1em 0;
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    margin: 0.7em 0;
  }
  h3 {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0.5em 0;
  }
  h4 {
    font-size: 1.4em;
    margin: 0.3em 0;
  }
  h5 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 0.2em 0;
  }
  h6 {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    margin: 0.2em 0;
  }
  p {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 0.4em 0;
  }
  .caption {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  header {
    min-height: 600px;
  }
  section {
    padding: 10px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  section {
    padding: 15px 10px;
  }
  .pull-right {
    float: none !important;
  }
  #orders {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    text-align: center;
  }
  header,
  header .caption {
    position: static;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #orders-mobile {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    min-height: auto;
  }
  form #submit {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    float: none;
  }
  .col-sm-3,
  .col-sm-4 {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  #orders-below .col-sm-4 a {} .marketplace-tabs-nulled .items a {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: block;
  }
  .marketplace-tabs-nulled .items span {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    font-size: 2.3em;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="container group">

      <h3 class="sec-title">Blah marketplace to run world's best Retail</h3>
      <p class="subtitle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vitae dui et orci dapibus auctor a ac augue.</p>

      <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Full Name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
            <span>Invalid</span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
            <span>Enter a password longer than 8 characters</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="mobile" placeholder="Mobile no...">
            <span>Invalid</span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <textarea id="textarea" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Enter details..."></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" id="filled-data"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info text-center pull-right">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You have to use `e.preventDefault()` at `$("#submit").click`

Comment: Okay. after doing this on submit button. How do i go about actual submission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you press the submit button, it **does** display, but at the same time, posts to the page. So the page technically gets refreshed. So add `return false` or `e.preventDefault()` so that it doesn't post it or refresh the page:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    $filledHtml += $textarea.val();
    $('#filled-data').html(filledHtml).addClass('small');
    return false;
});
```

And later you can use `$.post()` or `$.get()` to submit your form data and show it to your screen.

The other error is, that you have `filledHtml` not equal to `$filledHtml`. Forgot a dollar sign:

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
  $filledHtml += $textarea.val();
  debugger;
  $('#filled-data').html($filledHtml).addClass('small');
  //---------------------^ Add dollar here.
  return false;
});
```

Comment: @PraveenKumar I tried adding return false. but the div is of `filled-data' class is still empty.

Comment: Its a special touch for you only :)

Comment: @MegaRacer Is the div empty after clicking?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yes. Please do a code review if the function calls and string is building the right way from all fields.

Comment: @MegaRacer Doing it. `:)`

Comment: @MegaRacer In your snippet, you forgot to include jQuery. Duh! `:P`

Comment: @MegaRacer `enableSubmitEvent()` is undefined.

Comment: NO no..Jquery and all is there. Just missed it over here to state explicitly as this was a snippet

Comment: @MegaRacer Snippet's main intention is to get the problem working and reproduceable here... `:)`

Comment: Ok. But when I pasted all code the characters exceeded. Wait i'll do something

Comment: @MegaRacer Don't do anythign... I will take care.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100230/discussion-between-megaracer-and-praveen-kumar).